# How do I get the software update list to update?

Tags: wine, software-updates, zorin

[image: out of date list notice]I'm on Zorin, trying to get some windows programs working, but Wine is hung on version 1.6, and I can't figure out how to tell it to get a new update list. Each time I try to update a program, I get a warning that my update list is out of date and I haven't been able to find out how to update the update list to get WINE up to date. Direct download through the terminal didn't work, either.

Mostly trying to get battle.net working so I can game as normal before completely abandoning my old box.

Answer (score 0):

Since Zorin is based on Ubuntu, you can install newer versions of Wine by following [the instructions on the wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu):

- enable `i386`:

  ```
  https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu
  ```
- add the WineHQ repositories:

  ```
  wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
  sudo apt-key add Release.key
  sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
  ```
- update the package index:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  ```
- install the latest stable release (3.0):

  ```
  sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
  ```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked, and somewhere in my fumbling about Wine seems to have been removed.